# Python Dash hoverData x value

Tags: python, callback, hover, plotly-dash

My `hoverData` returns an object like this:

```
{
    'points': [{
        'curveNumber': 3,
        'pointNumber': 25,
        'pointIndex': 25,
        'x': '      2017 Feb',
        'y': 0.98
    }]
}
```

code:

```
@app.callback(dash.dependencies.Output("div_table1", 'children'),
              [dash.dependencies.Input('graph1', 'hoverData')])
def update_table1(hover_graph1):
   print(hover_graph1)
```

Is it a list?

How can I get the x value `'      2017 Feb'` from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a nested dictionary, so you just need to do this:

```
hover_graph1['points'][0]['x']
```